# Windows procmon: how to capture only events from a specific command?

Tags: windows, process-monitor

[Sysinternals procmon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) is sometimes invaluable, but I often find it awkward to use as I typically have to wade through a lot of irrelevant results to find what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to diagnose an issue with a specific command, so ideally I'd like to tell procmon what to start, and have it automatically start capturing, run the command, wait for exit and then stop capturing.

Is this possible?

Comment: Does the command span new child processes or is it just this one command/executable? If it is just one process just use and include filter using the context menu of a matching event.

Comment: @Robert Children as well, as otherwise I think I could just use the 'Include' filter option. Btw I phrased my question generally, but the specific command I'm trying to 'monitor' is wsl, which definitely calls a fair few other services.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find ANY instance of the command under the process name column.
2. Right click directly on the `Process Name` and select `Include <process_name_here>`.
3. You can narrow it down from there but that will limit the flood of crap coming into the window.

As you mention in your comments, you might need to be tricky and limit your filter to a particular path if you are trying to monitor WSL and not worry about the process name.

I myself like to filter out all of the "crap" via a common filter I created before I even start.  It takes a few minutes, but instead of the method I describe above, I start right clicking on stuff I don't care about and exclude those items.  Eventually, the window calms down and I can start figuring out what else is going on.

Sometimes, I need to back-out a filter I added.. because the thing I was looking for disappeared.

Using the filters in this tool is an art.  This art will make you a bada$$.